# Get Email Status from Google in Java

Tags: java, rest, google-admin-sdk

I am working on an application that is authenticated by Google for the login part. The application is on AngularJS and is managed by Java RESTful services. The domain that we are using is managed by Google. The requirement is that I need a service from back end to check with Google if the email is still active or not. Let us say that the Admin disabled or suspended a user while the user was logged in. I need a way to check with Google if this email is still active or not. The only way that I found so far is by having the user name and password.
I wanted to know if it is possible if Google can call my service for me to disable the user from my end and if it was not possible how can I check the user status without the need of using the password.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Arent you "solution architect" ?

Comment: Yes I am a Solutions Architect